# Скачивание БД кликом по кнопке

Tags: javascript, php

Можно ли как-то сделать кнопку, нажатие которой приведет к экспорту определенной БД из phpmyadmin?
Т.е у пользователя в личном кабинете будет обычная кнопка button и по клику на нее пользователю на его ПК должна скачаться БД, то бишь экспорт БД.
Попробовал таким образом, но ничего не скачивает

```
<?php
    # Если кнопка нажата
    if( isset( $_POST['dump'] ) )
    {
       $host = "localhost";
    $username = "1";
    $password = "1";
    $dbname = "1";

    // open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    // fetch mysql table rows
    $sql = "select * from user";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $fp = fopen('books.csv', 'w');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);

    }
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="dump" value="dump" />
</form>
```

Comment: В phpmyadmin встроен экспорт.
Абсолютно не понятно что вы имеете ввиду, дополните вопрос

Comment: @Dizzy221 дополнил, не знаю как подробнее описать

Comment: Может помочь кто-нибудь?

Comment: Посмотрите тут
https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-csv-file-using-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Экспорт базы данных значит забрать данные.
Проще всего зайти в саму базу данных и нажать экспорт.
Вы можете забрать все данные из базы данных,но вам тогда самим их придётся структуровать.
Вот например вы можете обратится к базе данных и забрать все id из неё то есть сделать экспорт базы данных если там только id.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "имя бд", "пароль", "имя бд"); // подключение к базе данных


$mysqli->query ("SET NAMES 'utf8' "); // кодировка


function printResult ($result_set) { 
while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false)  // вытягиваем по одному значению
{
    global $q40;
    $q40=$row['id']; 
    echo $q40;//выводим id на экран


}

}



$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM  `156`"); // например таким образом мы из базы 156 достаём все id


printResult ($result_set); // отправляем в функцию


$mysqli->close();// закрытие бд
```